# How to sort a list containing frozensets (python)

Tags: python, list, data-structures, set

I have a list of frozensets that I'd like to sort, Each of the frozensets contains a single integer value that results from an intersection operation between two sets:

```
k = frozenset(w) & frozenset(string.digits)
d[k] = w # w is the value
list(d) # sorted(d) doesn't work since the keys are sets and sets are unordered.
```

Here is the printed list:

```
[frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'4'}), frozenset({'3'})]
```

How can I sort the list using the values contained in the sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide function as `key` to `sorted` which would accept `frozenset` as argument and return something which might be compared. If each `frozenset` has exactly 1 element and said element is always single digit then you might use `max` function (it will extract that single element, as sole element is always biggest element of `frozenset`) that is

```
d1 = [frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'4'}), frozenset({'3'})]
d2 = sorted(d1,key=max)
print(d2)
```

output

```
[frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'3'}), frozenset({'4'})]
```

If you want to know more read [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Nice use of max function

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, unless you really need to keep the elements as `frozenset`, the best might be to generate a list of values upstream (`[2, 1, 4, 3]`).

Anyway, to be able to sort the frozensets you need to make them ordered elements, for instance by converting to `tuple`. You can do this transparently using the `key` parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
l = [frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'4'}), frozenset({'3'})]

sorted(l, key=tuple)
```

or **[`natsorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/5.4.1/natsorted.html) for strings with multiple digits**:

```
from natsort import natsorted
l = [frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'14'}), frozenset({'3'})]

natsorted(l, key=tuple)
```

output:

```
[frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'3'}), frozenset({'14'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers can not sorted correctly, Because of strings

```
d = [frozenset({'224'}), frozenset({'346'}), frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'22345'})]
sorted(d, key=lambda x: int(list(x)[0]))
```

Output:

```
[frozenset({'2'}),
 frozenset({'224'}),
 frozenset({'346'}),
 frozenset({'22345'})]
```

Comment: good point (I had not realized they were strings), however better use natsorted for that (see my update)

Comment: @mozway Kiragu create `frozenset` by `frozenset(w) & frozenset(string.digits)` which always will give single digits